# PHP flock() with Simplexml open, read and write

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, file-locking, flock

I was wondering whether it is possible to open, read and write from an xml file using simplexml in a PHP file lock. If it is not possible, how can I achieve locking a file and reading/writing into it using simple xml at the same time?

For example:

```
$file = fopen('text.xml', 'r+');

flock($file, LOCK_EX);

if (file_exists('test.xml'))
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
    //Retrieve xml element, 
    //Save XML element back to test.xml here
    print_r($xml);
}
else
{
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}

flock($file, LOCK_UN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `fread` to get the contents as a string, then parse with `simplexml_load_string` instead of `simplexml_load_file`:

```
$file = fopen('text.xml', 'r+');

flock($file, LOCK_EX);

// Load the data
$data = fread($file, filesize('text.xml'));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

// Modify here

// Save it back
$new_data = $xml->asXML();
ftruncate($file);
rewind($file);
fwrite($file, $new_data);

flock($file, LOCK_UN);
fclose($file);
```

Error-handling omitted from the example for simplicity; you should be checking if `$file` is a valid handle, and also if `$xml` is a valid SimpleXMLElement.